# Не работает вывод результатов динамического поиска на laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Дело такое пишу вот этот код отдельно оно работает и показывает данные из базы данных без обновлении на аяксе.

Вот это я перенес в laravel проект и там оно не работает
токены туда сюда добавлял эти так и по другому
{'referal':$(this).val(), _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'}

Но в поиске ничего не показывает

И все это находится в одном файле пробовал в стиле laravel разделить их по контроллерам и все такое но все равно не работает в чем может быть проблема можете подсказать Заранее спасибо

```js
$(function(){
    
    //Живой поиск
    
    
    $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
        if(this.value.length >= 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                
                type: 'POST',
                url: "#", //Путь к обработчику
                data: {'referal':this.value},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); //Выводим полученые данные в списке
                }
            })  
        }
    })
    
    $(".search_result").hover(function(){
        $(".who").blur(); //Убираем фокус с input
    })
    
    //При выборе результата поиска, прячем список и заносим выбранный результат в input
    $(".search_result").on("click", "li", function(){
        s_user = $(this).text();
        //$(".who").val(s_user).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //деактивируем input, если нужно
        $(".search_result").fadeOut();
    })

})
```

```html
В хедере
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

В теле
<input type="text" name="referal" placeholder="Поиск" class="who" >
<ul class="search_result"></ul>

<?php

define("DB_HOST","localhost");
        define("DB_NAME","helix02_db"); //Имя базы
        define("DB_USER","root"); //Пользователь
        define("DB_PASSWORD",""); //Пароль

        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $mysqli -> query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die ("Ошибка соединения с базой!");

        if(!empty($_POST["referal"])){ //Принимаем данные
            $referal = trim(strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["referal"]))));


            $db_referal = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * from `services` search WHERE name LIKE '%$referal%'")
            or die('Ошибка №'.__LINE__.'<br>Обратитесь к администратору сайта пожалуйста, сообщив номер ошибки.');

            while ($row = $db_referal -> fetch_array()) {
                echo "\n<a href='https://helix-almaty.kz/services/show/".$row["model"]."'><li class='odo'>".$row["name"]."</li></a>"; //$row["name"] - имя таблицы
            }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Она только на laravel е не работает а отдельно работает все нормально

Comment: Искал похожие задачи но те варианты тоже не помогли

Comment: вот метод laravel 

public function AjaxSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $text_input = $request->input('text_input');
        $name = Service::all()->where('name','like' , "%{$text_input}%")->get();
        return response()->json($name);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы делаете запрос ajax, а в него не добавляете сам этот хеадер. По факту нужен такой код, перед самим `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Подробней почитайте вот тут: [Laravel documentation: X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)